# I have a [slug] "dynamic page" which works perfectly fine in LOCALHOST but shows a 404 in VERCEL and GITHUB

Tags: github, next.js, github-pages, next.js13

I have developed a website with homepage.  homepage/blog and homepage/blog/[slug].

Everthing works fine in LOCALHOST.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i1RP.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGhMI.jpg)

But in GITHUB and VERCEL I get 404 when I try access homepage/blog/[slug] as homepage/blog/1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIrtX.jpg)

Please check my repo it would help me alot if you can find a solution.

Repo link:-https://github.com/ManideepVaddepalli/TeamApp-BlogPage-NextJS

Live Server:-https://manideepvaddepalli.github.io/TeamApp-BlogPage-NextJS

I cant figure out the issue.

I just want the app to work similar as in LOCALHOST with dynamic pages [slug].

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you might want to try https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath

Comment: Yes, as @CodeThing mentioned, you need to configure basepath, on localhost, you are accessing blog page without any sub directory, however on server you have a sub directory "TeamApp-BlogPage-NextJS"

Comment: If I add even my [homepage/blog] page is not showing up.  just to mention -   My all static directly created pages are working fine .  only the [slug] pages are not working in GITHUB and VERCEL where as they are doing fine in LOCALHOST.          Please I also gave the link to my repo You can download and check it in your local environment.  Hope you find a solution

Comment: and a reminder i have replaced the anchor tags with "./" path instead of "/".   If this could be helpful in debug

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.